# Stored Procedure from excel

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a excel sheet and column B has data like below example.

```
007108080600071762

007108080800024102
```

I am trying to run this command through a excel below through my data connection

```
declare
  @iMag char(18),
  @oOCR varchar(10)

set @iMag = '007108080600071762'

exec GW_MAGtoOCR @iMAG, @oOCR output

select CardNumber from cds_card where cardnumber = (select @oOCR)
```

The line where it says `Set @iMag = '007108080600071762'`

I would like that to read from column B and insert the answer to the query in Column C.

Any help would be appreciated.

I already did the ODBC connection to the data base on from other sources menu.